# Win32 - Button images appear in wrong order in toolbar

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I am creating a simple Paint application using win32 api (in visual studio). I have created a toolbar and added a bitmap for 10 toolbar images (TBbuttons.bmp - size: 160x16 pixel - 4bpp indexed format) as below:

[image: bmp file used as bitmap]

However the button images do not appear in the correct order as shown above and, moreover, some images have a black line above them (which is not what i intended):
[image: Application image]

Here is the code i use to create the toolbar as well as those buttons:

```
    InitCommonControls();
    //create initial buttons
    TBBUTTON tbButtons[] =
    {
        { STD_FILENEW,  IDM_NEW, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0},
        { STD_FILEOPEN, IDM_OPEN, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0},
        { STD_FILESAVE, IDM_SAVE, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0}
    };

    //Create toolbar window
    HWND hToolBarWnd = CreateToolbarEx(hWndParent,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CCS_ADJUSTABLE | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS,
        ID_TOOLBAR, sizeof(tbButtons) / sizeof(TBBUTTON), HINST_COMMCTRL,
        0, tbButtons, sizeof(tbButtons) / sizeof(TBBUTTON),
        BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT,
        sizeof(TBBUTTON));

    //Add more buttons
    TBBUTTON buttonsToAdd[] =
    {
        { 0, 0, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_SEP, 0, 0 },
        { STD_CUT,  IDM_CUT, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { STD_COPY, IDM_COPY, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { STD_PASTE, IDM_PASTE, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { STD_DELETE, IDM_DELETE, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 }
    };
    SendMessage(hToolBarWnd, TB_ADDBUTTONS, (WPARAM)sizeof(buttonsToAdd) / sizeof(TBBUTTON),
        (LPARAM)(LPTBBUTTON)&buttonsToAdd);

    //Create 10 more buttons to draw
    TBBUTTON userButtons[] =
    {   
        { 0, 0,                     TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_SEP, 0, 0 },
        { 0, IDM_ELLIPSE,           TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { 1, IDM_FILLED_ELLIPSE,    TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { 2, IDM_RECT,              TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { 3, IDM_FILLED_RECT,       TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { 4, IDM_CIRCLE,            TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { 5, IDM_FILLED_CIRCLE,     TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { 6, IDM_SQUARE,            TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { 7, IDM_FILLED_SQUARE,     TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { 8, IDM_LINE,              TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { 9, IDM_TEXT,              TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 }
    };

    TBADDBITMAP tbBitmap = { hInst, IDB_BITMAP1 };
    //Add bitmap to toolbar
    int idx = SendMessage(hToolBarWnd, TB_ADDBITMAP, (WPARAM)sizeof(tbBitmap) / sizeof(TBADDBITMAP),
        (LPARAM)(LPTBADDBITMAP)&tbBitmap);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        userButtons[i].iBitmap += idx;
    }

    //Add button to toolbar
    SendMessage(hToolBarWnd, TB_ADDBUTTONS, (WPARAM)sizeof(userButtons) / sizeof(TBBUTTON),
        (LPARAM)(LPTBBUTTON)&userButtons);
```

I am still new to win32 api and i have no idea what is the cause of this. The application still runs fine but the buttons images are completely wrong. How can i fix this? Is it because of my code or the bitmap i created that caused the issue?

**EDIT**: I added a new bitmap i found from the Internet (TBbitmap2.bmp) as a test and created anew another bitmap (TBbitmap3.bmp) similar to the first one. Of all 3 bitmaps, the first one produced the problem in the question and the other 2 bitmaps worked fine. Here is [the link to all 3 bitmaps](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19vcppdPu8lD8kUaWwYwtAlv36DShE6PT?usp=sharing). The question remains **why the first bitmap kept producing the problem but the other 2 worked?** (they have the same properties just different size).

Comment: I tested the code and it has no problem. I think the problem is caused by the created bitmap. Could you provide the created bitmap to help us reproduce the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to upload .bmp file to Stack Overflow so here is the google Drive [link to the bitmap i used](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19vcppdPu8lD8kUaWwYwtAlv36DShE6PT?usp=sharing).
It is the same as the bitmap in my question

Comment: The `wParam` argument for `TB_ADDBITMAP` should be the number of images in the bitmap, whereas you're passing `sizeof(tbBitmap) / sizeof(TBADDBITMAP)` which will equal 1.

Comment: I changed the argument you said to the number of buttons (which is 10 here) and the problem still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a sample and used the bitmap.

It does have some weird behavior. After I built the project for the first time, it did produce the problem you said. But after I rebuilt, the problem disappeared:

[image]

I think the bitmap was not loaded correctly during the build process, maybe you can try to rebuild the project and run the program.

Comment: I rebuilt the project many times but the problem still remained. However, i created a new bitmap and it worked now. Please refer to the new edit in my question for details.

Comment: @Halsey After my test, I found that Visual Studio will modify the picture. You need to enter the resource view -> Bitmap to select the bitmap, and then save it, and it can be displayed normally.

Comment: Thanks for your constant replies. I followed your advice and the situation remains (the first bitmap still causes the problem, other two work). I have no idea what is wrong with it.

Comment: @Halsey I checked three bitmaps (opened through Notepad), I found that the bitmaps starting with BMv can be displayed normally, while the ones starting with BM6 will have this problem. I think there is a problem with your bitmap format, but I can pass Save the bitmap in VS to modify it.

Comment: @Zhu that does the trick. It really is just as you said. I modified and save the first bitmap (in resource view that you mentioned) and it is displayed normally now.

Answer (score 0):

The default toolbar button image size is not 16 x 16, it's 16 x 15. The exact size will show up in the toolbar resource declaration in the .rc file.

Also, some paint programs (e.g. Paint.net) even though they can save e.g. 4-bit BMPs do not do so in quite the same way Visual Studio does, and that can cause buttons to appear in the wrong place.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).